# Apache 307 Redirect to redirect POST data

Tags: apache, .htaccess

PayPal are annoying...if you have thousands of customer subscriptions which `POST` IPN's (Instant Payment Notifications) to a certain URL...you can never change that URL. If you want to have the IPN's sent to another URL, their advice...tell all your customers to cancel their subscriptions and start new ones after you've changed the IPN URL. Great.

So after digging around, a solution I found is to use a 307 redirect which will not only redirect to a new URL, but carry along the `POST` data with it. but I'm having a little trouble with that in Apache. It doesn't seem to work at all. Here is the line in my `.htaccess` file:

```
Redirect 307 /index.php?view=account&task=paypal https://api.anotherdomain.com/paypal/ipn
```

What would be the reason this doesn't redirect?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can't match against querystring using a Redirec directive. You need to match against %{QUERY_STRING} variable using mod-rewrite. The following rule does what you want :

```
RewriteEngine on

RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^view=account&task=paypal$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^/?index\.php$ http://example.com/paypal/? [R=307,L]
```

**?** at the end of the destination url is important as it avoids appending old querystring to the new url.

Comment: Sir...you are a star! Thank you.

Comment: Just a question, what is the reason for the **?** in front of `index.php`?

Comment: @wasim /? means the rule is available for use in both contexts (htaccess and server.config) .